# gem Warden, why do I need scope: in login_as helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, capybara, warden

After looking at somebody else's code I have noticed the following:

```
login_as user, scope: :user
```

I have always used simply

```
login_as user
```

So I went out to look for an explanation and found this article [How to: Test with Capybara](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara) that says use `scope: :user` however without any explanation. All my tests are working fine without it.

Another strange thing is `Warden.test_mode!` which I am not using either. Why would I need it?

Any explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.**
As you can see [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/warden/Warden/Test/Helpers:login_as), `login_as` calls `set_user` with the same set of options.

Here's the [source code](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/warden/Warden/Proxy:set_user) of `set_user` (click "View source"). On line 165, you'll see that if the `:scope` option is empty, the default scope will be used. In your Rails application, open `config/initializers/devise.rb`, you'll find something as follows

```
# Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
# devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
# config.default_scope = :user
```

It means your default scope is `:user` which is used when you call `login_as` without passing a scope.

**2.**
Here's the documentation of `Warden.test_mode!`

> .test_mode! ⇒ Object
>
> Provides helper methods to warden for testing.
>
> To setup warden in test mode call the test_mode! method on warden
>
> This will provide a number of methods. Warden.on_next_request(&blk) -
>   captures a block which is yielded the warden proxy on the next request
>   Warden.test_reset! - removes any captured blocks that would have been
>   executed on the next request
>
> Warden.test_reset! should be called in after blocks for rspec, or
>   teardown methods for Test::Unit

It means if you're sure you won't need/use any of the helper methods provided by warden as listed, not calling this method won't break your tests.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpfull https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/authenticated-session-data .
`scope` is used to separate session data for logged_in entities (eg. :user and :admin).
Warden allows You to have one session with more entities logged_in at same time.